# Troubleshooting "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE" in nested if blocks

Tags: php, if-statement

I have the following code on my website:

```
<?php
$loggedout = $_GET["loggedout"];
if ($loggedout=="true") { 
echo '<body class="slider-header" onload="Modalbox.show(\'/data/loggedout\',{width: 576, title: \'Logged Out\'}); return false;">'; else { 
if (isset($_COOKIE["hide"]))
  echo '<body class="slider-header">';
else
  echo '<body class="slider-header" onload="Modalbox.show(\'/data/surveyinvite\',{width: 576, title: \'Website Survey\'}); return false;">';
}; ?>
```

What this should do is determine if `$loggedout` equals true and, if so, display `/data/loggedout`.  If `$loggedout` is not true (or not present), it should then go on to determine if the cookie `hide` exists.  If the cookie does exist, there should be no `onload` and if the cookie does not exist, it should display `/data/surveyinvite`.

However, I get the following error when going to my page:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   T_ELSE in
>   /home/briefs/public_html/index.php on
>   line 16

Line 16 is

```
echo '<body class="slider-header" onload="Modalbox.show(\'/data/loggedout\',{width: 576, title: \'Logged Out\'}); return false;">'; else {
```

I have determined that issue is somewhere in the following (if I get rid of it, `$loggedout` works as expected):

```
if (isset($_COOKIE["hide"]))
  echo '<body class="slider-header">';
else
  echo '<body class="slider-header" onload="Modalbox.show(\'/data/surveyinvite\',{width: 576, title: \'Website Survey\'}); return false;">';
};
```

Where is the issue in this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you indent your code properly and *always* use brackets (I know they're not required; do it anyway, because it prevents stupid mistakes like this) then you'll find it much easier to not make such a simple mistake.  You were missing several curly brackets, that's all.

```
<?php
$loggedout = $_GET["loggedout"];
if ($loggedout=="true") { 
    echo '<body class="slider-header" onload="Modalbox.show(\'/data/loggedout\',{width: 576, title: \'Logged Out\'}); return false;">'; 
} else { 
    if (isset($_COOKIE["hide"])) {
        echo '<body class="slider-header">';
    } else {
        echo '<body class="slider-header" onload="Modalbox.show(\'/data/surveyinvite\',{width: 576, title: \'Website Survey\'}); return false;">';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: +1 , although brackets are not required all the time, it is considered good practice to use brackets anytime you can. it will help you indent your code and this way you could have rectified your problem easily.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely best practice; every set of PHP code standards I've ever seen recommends it because it's too easy to make mistakes if you don't.

Comment: I usually indent everything, but I didn't here and it got me frustrated and too annoyed to find an error I should have found.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some curly brackets "{" and "}" should read:

```
<?php
$loggedout = $_GET["loggedout"];
if ($loggedout=="true") { 
echo '<body class="slider-header" onload="Modalbox.show(\'/data/loggedout\',{width: 576, title: \'Logged Out\'}); return false;">'; else { 
if (isset($_COOKIE["hide"])) { # <-- here
  echo '<body class="slider-header">';
  }   else { # <-- here
   echo '<body class="slider-header" onload="Modalbox.show(\'/data/surveyinvite\',{width: 576, title: \'Website Survey\'}); return false;">';
  } # <-- and here
}; ?>
```